# php script to detect links needed in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following php code to detect and replace links:

```
//Detect links
    $pattern_url='~(?>[a-z+]{2,}://|www\.)(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?@)?(?:(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])(?:\.[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?:/[^\\/:?*"<>|\n]*[a-z0-9])*/?(?:\?[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?(?:&[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?)*)?(?:#[a-z0-9_%.]+)?~i';
    preg_match_all($pattern_url, $post, $matches); 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        if(substr($matches[0][$i],0,4)=='www.')
        $post = str_replace($matches[0][$i],'http://'.$matches[0][$i],$post);
    }
    $post = preg_replace($pattern_url,'<a target="_blank" href="\\0">\\0</a>', $post);
```

I would like to have the same in javascript/jquery.

How is that possible?

Comment: The right answer would be `by implementing it in javascript` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
   var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
   return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

[How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)